# My search to find best selling products isn't returning the expected results

Tags: mysql, sorting, search, sum

How can I select the products titles( or *) ordering by best selling? There are two related tables, transactions:

```
id|product_id|amount
-------------------------
 1|   1      |   1
 2|   1      |   3 
 3|   2      |   3 
 4|   2      |   1 
 5|   1      |   7
```

Product info:

```
id|title     |
--------------
 1|  DVD1    |
 2|  Bag     | 
 3|  DVD2    | 
 4|Playstaion| 
 5|  Xbox    |
```

Comment: you have to `JOIN`, it's relation DB 101.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.id,p.title,SUM(t.amount) as SOLD FROM products p INNER JOIN
transactions t on p.id=t.product_id
GROUP BY p.id,p.title
ORDER BY SUM(t.amount) DESC
```

Result:

```
ID  TITLE   SOLD
1   DVD1    11
2   Bag     4
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49036/7).

**EDIT:**

For displaying unsold items also, we have to use `LEFT JOIN` and `IF NULL()`.

```
SELECT p.id,p.title,IFNULL(SUM(t.amount),0) as SOLD 
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
transactions t on p.id=t.product_id
GROUP BY p.id,p.title
ORDER BY SUM(t.amount) DESC
```

Result:

```
ID  TITLE         SOLD
1   DVD1          11
2   Bag           4
3   DVD2          0
4   Playstaion    0
5   Xbox          0
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49036/19).

**Explanation:**

`IF NULL()` returns 0 if the parameter is null.

Comment: Thank, it works great except that if an existing product does not exist in transactions table( zero sales ), it is not selected. I also need to display products with no sales.

Comment: @user3325861: Edited my answer. Non-sold items will also be selected in the new query.